# C programming , recursion

Tags: c, recursion

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){

    static int n=7;
    
    if(n){
        n--;
        main();
        printf("%d",n);
    }

}
```

Sol: I was trying to trace the recursion. In my logic answer should be 1234567, but the answer is 000000. My question is how to trace this recursion?

Comment: Note that `n` is `static`.  So there's only one of it.  And by the time any of the `main`'s start printing it, all the subtractions have been done.

Comment: @pmg That's the sort of thing that happens when people retype their code here, rather than copying and pasting.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are calling main before printing.

if you do:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){

    static int n=7;
    
    if(n){
        n--;
        // main();
        printf("%d",n);

        main();
    }
    return;
}
```

You will get the output: 6543210

But in your case, it will print only when the value of n is 0. And since 7 print is pending therefore 0000000

Answer (score 1):

There exists only one variable since it's static. A slight modification (including the fix of void return type) demonstrates it:

#include <stdio.h>

```
int main(void)
{
    static int n=7;

    if(n) {
        n--;
        printf("%d",n);
        main();
        printf("%d",n);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
65432100000000
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to trace it probably is using `gdb` to follow it along.

If you declare `n` as static, it's value would be preserved across function calls. Note that you are calling printf **after** the recursive step (calling `main`). This causes `printf` to see the value of `n` after all the calls to `main`.

Think of this sequence, executing with n = 2

```c
if (n) // first time, n == 2.
n--; // n == 1
main();
  if (n) // second time, n == 1
  n--;
  main();
    if (n) // third time, n == 0, fails
  printf("%d",n); // n == 0.
printf("%d",n); // n == 0.
```